# Change skaffold command for Cloud Code VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, skaffold

I'm using the Cloud Code extension for VSCode and each time I'm deploying, the `skaffold` command executed is the following:

```
skaffold run --enable-rpc -v info --rpc-http-port 33291 --default-repo gcr.io/project-1`
```

while in my skaffold.yaml file I have the following configuration `build.artifacts[].context.image: gcr.io/project-2/hello-world`

Thus after the build step, the deployment continues with

```
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/project-1/gcr.io/project-2/hello-world]
```

Of course... this is not what I'm expecting.

Locally, my gcloud is using an account which has access to both project so that skaffold (docker) push works and my gcr.io/project-1 is populated accordingly.

But my Cloud Run service in project-2 is not granted rights to access gcr.io/project-1 and deployment (`image pull`) fails.

Please, do you know where to change that default skaffold command when running Cloud Deploy (and update the destination registry)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you generate your `skaffold.yaml` from the Cloud Code Extension?  If not, ideally it shouldn't contain `gcr.io/project-2` prefix, because the exension adds it.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer or leave a comment if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Well. I did for one of my apps. The other one was just the Go Hello world sample available directly in the Code Cloud Github repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the registry Cloud Code vscode extension pushes to, go to settings:

[image]

and in the Extensions → Cloud Code section, change the image registry setting:

[image]

If you can't get it to work, try deleting your local `.vscode` directory and do a `Cloud Code: Build` again, that way it'll ask for your container registry URI again.

Comment: That's it. Exactly. Thank you very much.